# Cartesian join two tables with no records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join Table A (tax related) to Table B (customer related)

I pull at most 1 record but sometimes no record.

Now I need to return the combined record to the user

I though doing a simple Cartesian product would have work

```
SELECT * FROM TableA, TableB
```

but that does not work if TableA or TableB is empty

I would do a full outer join but right now do not have anything to join on.  I could create temp tables with identity columns and then join on them (since 1 = 1)

But I was looking for a different way?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per your own suggestion, you could use a `full outer join` to guarantee a row:

```
select  *
        TableA a
full outer join
        TableB b
on      1=1
```

To always return at least one row, even if `TableA` and `TableB` are emtpy, you could use a fake table:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  1 as col1
        ) fake
left join
        TableA a
on      1=1
left join
        TableB b
on      1=1
```

Comment: Thanks that led me down the right road but I did FROM #TaxPiece TaxPiece 
full outer join #TaxAddress TaxAddress on 1=1  thank you

Comment: Btw, I am having a dilemma in marking this as the Correct answer.  While it helped me get to an answer, I wouldn't want to mark this as correct.  I also don't want to answer my own question since this one is close.  Would you consider updating your answer to not use the fake table.

Comment: I'll update the answer.  Note that this variant returns an empty set if both A and B are empty.